# Entity Framework 4.3 - Configuring ConnectionString with DataContext Interface

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string

I'm using EF 4.3 with Ninject.  I have a simple DataContext and I've created an interface for it.  It's a simple interface:

```
public interface IMyDataContext
{
    DbSet<ComplexType> ComplexTypes { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Implementation of MyDataContext:

```
    public class MyDataContext : DbContext, IMyDataContext
{
    public DbSet<ComplexType> ComplexTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); //Not sure if this is necessary.. 

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

And I'm adding it to NInject:

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyDataContext>().To<MyDataContext>();
```

Using the connection string name MyDataContext doesn't work and if I use IMyDataContext, it generates another database named the full assembly name.  Only one table/class is mapped.. not sure if that has anything to do with it.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDataContext"
     connectionString="Server=MyPc\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDataContext;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I know I can override the constructor on the data context.... but I thought this was supposed to "auto map".  Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a

```
Kernel.Bind<IMyDataContext()
    .To<MyDataContext()
    .WithConstructorArgument("nameOrConnectionString", "MyDataContext");
```

In conjunction with this:

```
public class MyDataContext : IMyDbContext, DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext (string nameOrConnectionString) 
       : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
}
```

To avoid any problem.

Also what is mapped depends on your DbSet<> declaration on your DbContext, you should also post the MyDataContext implementation.

Comment: Thanks - added the implementation above.  I was hoping for a way to just use the name of the datacontext - but I think this is juts as easy.  Appreciate it.